# Programmatically load files

Tags: r, windows

When I want to load a file into R, what would be a way to do so programmatically (or semi programmatically) instead of just manually copy paste the path and switch `\` to `/` so R could read it (because `\` is an escape character in R)

One method mentioned by [@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland) is using `scan`

```
list.files(scan(file=file(description = "clipboard"), what = "character", allowEscapes = FALSE))
```

Which will need modifications if the path contains a space like

> "C:\Users\David Arenburg\"

Comment: Use `/` if possible. You can use `normalizePath` if you have sources that contain `\ `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`normalizepath` maybe what you are looking for:

```
> normalizePath(c(R.home(), tempdir()))
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.0"                    
[2] "C:\\Users\\john\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpysKuFi"
> normalizePath(c(R.home(), tempdir()), winslash = '/')
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.0"                 
[2] "C:/Users/john/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpysKuFi"
```

Use `readClipboard` if you are on windows and have problems copying and pasting filepaths. For example I copy a file path from a windows folder so it is on the clip board then I can use:

```
> readClipboard()
[1] "C:\\Users\\john\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
```

You can then use `normalizePath to correct the windows flavour of paths.

Comment: The problem that i need to parse the path to `normalizePath` without having it stored somewhere. This is why I copy paste it from the file directory. I'm looking for something like `normalizePath(path = "C:\Users\")` which doesn't work

Comment: Why can't you store the path somewhere?

Comment: `'c:/users/david'` is valid in windows. store the directory path, `list.files`, read in data, ???

Comment: @DavidArenburg Maybe change title to reflect that its a windows problem with copying paths from clipboard otherwise the title maybe misleading to others.

Comment: Changed. But i actually hoped it could a question for Linux users too to share their methods and etc

Comment: @rawr, I know it valid on windows, but in order to paste that I'll need to change from `\` to `/` which is exactly what i was trying to avoid

Comment: why not type it was my point. how are you going to reproduce read.clipboard?

Comment: @ScottRitchie, Because R doesn't allow to do something like temp <- "C:\Users\"

Comment: @rawr see my answer below. This is some wrapper function I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use choose.files() to pick the file followed by normalizePath() if you want to convert its path name to R's forward slashes.

Comment: I'm familiar with `choose.files()`, but I don't want to do this manually every time i'm open the script.