# substitute single backslash in R

Tags: r, string, escaping

I have read some questions and answers on this topic in stack overflow but still don't know how to solve this problem:

My purpose is to transform the file directory strings in windows explorer to the form which is recognizable in R, e.g. C:\Users\Public needs to be transformed to C:/Users/Public, basically the single back slash should be substituted with the forward slash. However the R couldn't store the original string "C:\Users\Public" because the \U and \P are deemed to be escape character.

```
dirTransformer <- function(str){
   str.trns <- gsub("\\", "/", str)
   return(str.trns)
   }

str <- "C:\Users\Public"
dirTransformer(str)

> Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
```

What I am actually writing is a GUI, where the end effect is, the user types or pastes the directory into a entry field, pushes a button and then the program will process it automatically.

Would someone please suggest to me how to solve this problem?

Comment: `"C:\\Users\\Public"` - use double backslashes to denote literal backslashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well that means I have to manually modify the directory. My purpose to develop a function which process and transform the directory automatically without manual intervention.

Comment: You already manually typed `str <- "C:\Users\Public"`  - why not do it right and type `str <- "C:\\Users\\Public"`? Also, not `gsub("\\", "/", str)`, but `gsub("\\", "/", str, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That was just an simplified example. What I am actually writing is a GUI, where the user types or pastes the directory into a entry field, pushes a button and then the program will process it. The fixed = TRUE is a correction. Thanks

Comment: can you try `tools::normalizePath("C:\\Users\\Public","/",TRUE")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you need to use a backslash in the string in R, you need to put double backslash. Also, when you use `gsub("\\", "/", str)`, the first argument is parsed as a regex, and it is not valid as it only contains a single literal backslash that must escape something. In fact, you need to make `gsub` treat it as a *plain text* with `fixed=TRUE`.

However, you might want to use [**`normalizePath`**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/normalizePath.html), see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871178/what-is-the-best-practice-to-efficiently-load-files-into-r-windows).

Comment: normalizePath(readClipboard()) seems to be the best possible solution. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
dirTransformer <- function(str){
  str.trns <- gsub("\\\\", "/", str)
  return(str.trns)
}

str <- readline()
C:\Users\Public

dirTransformer(str)
```

I'm not sure how you intend the user to input the path into the GUI, but when using readline() and then typing C:\Users\Public unquoted, R reads that in as:

```
> str
[1] "C:\\Users\\Public"
```

We then want to replace "\\" with "/", but to escape the "\\" we need "\\\\" in the gsub.

I can't be sure how the input from the user is going to be read into R in your GUI, but R will most likely escape the \s in the string like it does when using the readline example. the string you're trying to create "C:\Users\Public" wouldn't normally happen.

Comment: Why use a regex at all with `gsub` if OP needs to replace a literal backslash? The only thing necessary to make it work with `gsub` is to disable parsing the first argument as a regular expression with `fixed=TRUE`.

Comment: I mostly wrote the answer to show that the "C:\Users\Public" string he's testing with doesn't really happen. And besides, what is the advantage of adding an extra argument over adding 2 backslashes, is it faster with `fixed = TRUE`? It's arguably a bit cleaner/clearer, but I wouldn't say that it's a very big deal.

Comment: Using a string replacement, no regex object is created and that *is* some overhead - or at least most people consider that an overhead. Surely not a big deal (in most cases).

Comment: This approach of using readline() is also helpful! Thanks for it. I will try to integrate it into the GUI i m writing.