# Reading LaTeX file in R: how to get get of single backslash

Tags: r, regex, latex

I am trying to read with R a LaTeX file with functions starting with the character \ . I would like to get rid of these backslashes (I would like to replace them by @ before treating the content of the file itself). I have seen some questions posted here (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164239/substitute-single-backslash-in-r) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685737/ignore-escape-characters-backslashes-in-r-strings)), but none of the proposed solution seems to work.

When I try

```
paragraph = "Let us begin with a note\footnote{This is a note.} and then we will see"
gsub("\\","@",paragraph,fixed=T)
```

I obtain

```
[1] "Let us begin with a note\footnote{This is a note.} and then we will see"
```

I understand that paragraph does not contain a real backslash as R thinks that \f is a character. But I do not know how to deal with it. the paragraph variable is in fact red from a file using ReadLines: maybe is there a function allowing to read \ as \?

How to perform this substitution of \ to @?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [stringi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html) package to escape the \ before you pass it to gsub.

```
library(stringi)
paragraph <-  stri_escape_unicode("Let us begin with a note\footnote{This is a note.} and then we will see")
gsub('\\',"@",paragraph,fixed=T)

[1] "Let us begin with a note@footnote{This is a note.} and then we will see"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem with stri_escape_unicode is that it also converts all other special characters such as ' (my LaTeX file is in french so that I have plenty of this). So when I use this function, ' becomes \\' and then the gsub puts @ at the wrong places...

Comment: @user3771535 can you add the lines of code where you read the LaTeX file? When I put the string 
`Let us begin with a note@footnote{This is a note.} and then we will see. D'accord` into a text file and read it using `readLine()` I get the result `[1] "Let us begin with a note\\footnote{This is a note.} and then we will see. D'accord"`. I can directly process this with `gsub('\\',"@",stringFromReadLines,fixed=T)` and get the desired result 
`[1] "Let us begin with a note@footnote{This is a note.} and then we will see. D'accord"`

Comment: Yeah you are right, I am a fool, when I read it from a file it comes with \\. Thanks a lot !!!